# Bold today's hours of operation in html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm designing my company's website and I'm wondering how I can make it so that in the hours of operation, it bolds the current day and today's hours.

```html
<div class='hours'>
  <h4>Hours of Operation</h4>
  <table class="opening-days">
    <tr>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <td>9am - 5pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <td>9am - 5pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <td>9am - 5pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <td>9am - 5pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <td>9am - 5pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Saturday</th>
      <td>Closed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Sunday</th>
      <td>Closed</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

That is the code that I have. I was thinking maybe I can add a javascript code to bold the current day. Please help me as I am not too familiar with JS. 
Here is a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q6b84r7y/4/

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `<th>` tags from your table because as far as I remember `<th>` tags are meant to be used instead the `<thead>` tag, and seeing as how they were technically being used inside an unwritten `<tbody>`(sidenote, I also added in the tbody tag)

the code is fairly straight forward, I feel, but comment if you have any questions.

**EDIT**
I realized that on Sundays the could would behave incorrectly as `today.getDay()` would return 0, so I added in a quick fix for that. If I can think of something more elegant I'll update it later, but this should work.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var today = new Date();
  var todaysHours = document.querySelector('.opening-days tr:nth-child(' + ( today.getDay() == 0 ? 7 : today.getDay() ) + ')');
  todaysHours.classList.add('bold')
});
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class='hours'>
  <h4>Hours of Operation</h4>
  <table class="opening-days">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="week-day">Monday</td>
        <td>9am - 5pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="week-day">Tuesday</td>
        <td>9am - 5pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="week-day">Wednesday</td>
        <td>9am - 5pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="week-day">Thursday</td>
        <td>9am - 5pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="week-day">Friday</td>
        <td>9am - 5pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="week-day">Saturday</td>
        <td>Closed</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="week-day">Sunday</td>
        <td>Closed</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to make the bold more prominent?

Comment: use CSS to increase the font-weight, or up the text size

Comment: Can also add a text-shadow to make it pop out more: text-shadow: 2px 0 #888;